# Mongoose Model.findOneAndUpdate

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm a bit stuck using the Model.findOneAndUpdate() function from Mongoose.

I tried this

```
module.exports.verifyUser = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { verify: true }}, {new: true}, callback);
};
```

But I can't seem to update the "verify" field which is made as a boolean in the schema here

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  verify: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  }
});
```

If you can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Are you sure that you have `user` with `username` value that you are trying to verify? Maybe you could add some logs, just to be sure?

Comment: I mean I'd think so because username is what the query is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Haha I missed something, it's supposed to be

```
var query = {username: username.username}; // This sets it to the object field
```

not

```
var query = {username: username}; // This sets it to the object
```